# Opening iOS keyboard by triggering focus on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, keyboard, focus

Trying to see if a solution was ever found for iOS preventing focus being given to an input programmatically?

https://jsfiddle.net/88bjy3rL/

```
$('div').on('touchstart', function(event) {
  $('textarea').focus();
  console.log('touchstart');
});

$("div").trigger('touchstart');
```

In the above example the touchstart event is still triggered on iOS, with the output of 'touchstart' using Safari Web Inspector, however the focus is not given to the textarea.

Clicking on the test word to manually fire the event will work in setting the focus (however wrapping the focus() in a setTimeout will not work)

Are there any actual working solutions to setting the focus to open the keyboard without user interaction?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Cordova, you can add the following to your config.xml.

```
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
```

This allows the keyboard to automatically open when setting focus on an input.